# Div width and height based on inner image width & height in jquery resizable() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Hi i have a resizable jquery div ,and an image inside this div .

```js
$( function() {
  var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("user_file");
  inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);
  function previewImages(){
    var fileList = this.files;
    var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
      var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
      $('.new-multiple').append('<div class="img-div"><img src="' + objectUrl + '" class="newly-added" /></div>');
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
    }

    $( ".img-div" ).draggable();
    $( ".img-div" ).resizable();
    $(".newly-added").on("click", function(e) {
      $(".newly-added").removeClass("img-selected");
      $(this).addClass("img-selected");
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).on("click", function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).is(".newly-added") === false) {
        $(".newly-added").removeClass("img-selected");
      }
    });
  } 
});
```

```css
.new-multiple {
  width:400px !important;
  height:400px !important;
  background:white;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}
  
.img-div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
} 

.newly-added {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
} 

.img-selected{
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px 6px rgb(206, 206, 206);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input   name="user_file[]" id="user_file" style="position: relative;overflow: hidden" multiple="" type="file">
<div class="new-multiple"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vd11qyzv/7/

Here i have to  set the image width , div width manually  for the initial loading

```
.img-div{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
 } 
 .newly-added{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

**if i didn't use this css then resizable will not work.**

But i don't want to do this . 
Because the uploaded image will become stretched or enlarged because of this manual width and height . Original image dimension will lost.

How can we solve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is lots of useful info here: [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Please research your issue first before posting.

Second, using the example I offered in the previous question you asked, we can gather this detail by using JavaScript, `var img = new Image();`, to create the image object, not in the DOM or Markup, and then get the dimensions from it once it is loaded.

**Snippet**

```
  var imgDim = {
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  };
  var newImg = new Image();
  $(newImg).attr({
    src: objectUrl,
    id: "img-" + key,
    class: "newly-added"
  }).load(function(e) {
    imgDim.width = this.width;
    imgDim.height = this.height;
    $(newImg).appendTo($newDiv).css({
      width: imgDim.width + "px",
      height: imgDim.height + "px"
    });
  });
  $(newImg).resizable();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(val);
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vd11qyzv/12/

**Update**

If you want to resize the image and retain the ratio, you can do this using a set Width or Height, and calculating a ratio value from that. For example, if you wanted to set the width to 200 pixels:

```
Nw = 200
Nh = Ih * (200/Iw)
```

**Snippet**

```
imgDim.width = 200;
imgDim.height = Math.floor(this.height * (200 / this.width));
```

If your original dimensions were 1536 x 2048, they would result in 200 x 266. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vd11qyzv/15/

Comment: Thank you friend . But in your js fiddle draggable function is not working . Could you please check

Comment: .img-div {
  display: inline-block;
 
} solve my problem

Comment: @abilasher the draggable does work; yet, it uses a handle. Same as I commented in the previous post.

Comment: @abilasher maybe this will help show you: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vd11qyzv/19/

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes in our code and update js fiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/prashantchaurasia/dksqu2hb/6/

```
css updated of following classes
.new-multiple{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  background:white;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-div{

} 
.newly-added{

}
```

Comment: thank you . i Checked this friend. But it is not correct way and the method is incorrect . Don't change the main html structure

Comment: give link for the new fiddle

Comment: sorry. this is also wrong . you are changing the main html and css structure